# RShiny: Reducing bootstrap table cell padding when using `bs_theme()`

Tags: css, r, bootstrap-4, shiny, datatables

```
# Header
## Load packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage("Test",
                 inverse = T,
                 collapsible = T,
                 theme = bs_theme(
                   version = 4,
                   bootswatch = "lux",
                   "font-size-base" = "1rem",
                   "table-cell-padding" = ".4rem"
                 ),
                 tabPanel(
                   title = "Data Tables", 
                   id = "data",
                   icon = icon("flask"),
                   fluidRow(
                     dataTableOutput("DT1")
                   )
                   
                 )
                 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$DT1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, 
              style = "bootstrap4",
              options = list(info = F,
                             searching = T,
                             paging = T,
                             autoWidth = T,
                             scrollX = T),
              filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
              class = 'cell-border stripe compact',
              rownames = F)
  })
  
}

##
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I am trying to create a table using the `bs_theme()` function from the `bslib` package, specifically using the theme `lux`. The tables are very large and the cells have massive padding.  Adding the `"table-cell-padding"` argument in `bs_theme()` doesn't change the cell sizes. How do I make the table compact and the cells tight around the numbers/column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `tags$style('#DT1 td {padding: 0}')`, how simple is that.

```r
# Header
## Load packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage("Test",
                 inverse = T,
                 collapsible = T,
                 theme = bs_theme(
                     version = 4,
                     bootswatch = "lux",
                     "font-size-base" = "1rem",
                     "table-cell-padding" = ".4rem"
                 ),
                 tabPanel(
                     title = "Data Tables", 
                     id = "data",
                     icon = icon("flask"),
                     fluidRow(
                         tags$style('#DT1 td {padding: 0}'),
                         # style = "width: 50%",
                         dataTableOutput("DT1")
                     )
                     
                 )
                 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$DT1 <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(mtcars, 
                  style = "bootstrap4",
                  options = list(info = F,
                                 searching = T,
                                 paging = T,
                                 autoWidth = T,
                                 scrollX = T),
                  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
                  class = 'cell-border stripe compact',
                  rownames = F)
    })
    
}

##
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Change the `padding: 0` to any valid css unit you want, here I changed to 0, no padding. It will seem that it doesn't work on left and right, that's because you have `autoWidth`, it will always use the full width of the parent node. So, if you want the width to be smaller, uncomment the `style` line above, you should see is't only half of the screen.

[image]